# We want to get live data from Multi-para patient Monitor

Tags: java, device, health-monitoring, medical

Want to fetch / get data from Multi-para patient monitor.

I have googled a lot but not able to get proper solution of the same. These monitors are mainly manufactured by Chinese and no documents regarding the same is provided.

In monitors LAN cable port is available and also one third party software named Central Station displaying the information on computer (we want to do the same but independently to analyse the data). But we don't have any way to contact this software manufacturer or not able to know how they are getting this data.

So any can help how we can do this or how i can find solution of the same.

Thanks.

Edit:

With help of `WIRESHARK` we are able to sniff network data and its looks like this:

[image]

From this i am atleast able to know that it gathers information from this two ip i.e. 192.168.2.34 and 192.168.2.35 and its port is 52435 and 47327 respective.

**Can any one tell how i can do the same thing with help of programming in java??**

Comment: Have you seen anything about OpenSpliceDDS ?

Comment: nope. will check for sure.

Comment: I am not really sure because I am not a lawyer but could reverse engineering their protocol and using an undocumented API be seen as license infringement? Just wanted to throw it into the room to think about.

Comment: Okies.If you are looking for Pub-Consumer model you can try it out.

Comment: have you tried to plot the raw data in any way (unsigned/twos complement or one/two bytes per sample) and then compare to the monitor graphic? There is a chance that it is just sequential data, with no much of a "protocol".